# Can we Protect 3 microservices api project with asp net identity jwt token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, microservices

I'm building Microservices using asp net core 3. My Question is can i protect Microservices with asp net identity? For example one identiy project protecting 3 Microservices project. I don't want to use Identity server.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use Identity server.

Just with ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Core Identity?

No that's not possible. ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't possess the ability to generate JWT tokens and only support Cookie authentication.

For JWT you need to either

- use an OpenIDConnect/OAuth2 provider (IdentityServer is one, OpenIddict ist another open source OIDC provider)
- use external OIDC/OAuth provider (Auth0, Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.)
- generate the JWT token yourself (Which is not recommended unless you very well understand JWT/ODIC and are an security expert, since wrong/incomplete implementations in it can lead to severe security issues vs the well established and hardened Identity Provider already existing)

> My Question is can i protect Microservices with asp net identity?

Generally, you can protect as many Microservices as you with with JWT tokens.

One thing to remember though is: OpenID/JWT token is not for authorization, its for authentication. Authentication means to validate the identity of the user.

As such, you should not put permissions inside these tokens other than "scopes". Fine grained permissions need to be managed by the service itself, using the token to identify the user and obtain the fine-grained permissions.

On the last topic [Identity vs Permissions](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/) is a useful article to better understand this.

Comment: AspNetCore 3.0: ["Authentication and authorization for SPAs"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0) chapter mentions about JWT Bearer. Looking over the generated code when create an AspNetCore 3.0 Angular with Authentication it's possible to see an `OidcConfigurationController`, as well the `ClientApp` (which is an Angular8 code) contains configs characteristics for the implementation of an OIDC flow for Auth. As well, AspNetCore3.0 is using the IdentityServer4 which allows to emit/validate JWTs.

Comment: @mihai: That is to use with IdentityServer (a non-microsoft opensource project), which the op doesn't want to use. The new ASP.NET Core templates invovling WebAPI are shipped with support for IdentityServer jwt authorization. ASP.NET Core Identity doesn't have the capabilities to generate JWT token. You can only consume JWT tokes with the `AddJwtBearer` call

Comment: Which is obvious from the first paragraph of the linked article: _ASP.NET Core 3.0 or later offers authentication in Single Page Apps (SPAs) using the support for API authorization. ASP.NET Core Identity for authenticating and storing users is combined with **IdentityServer** for implementing Open ID Connect._

Comment: thankiess @Tseng. Could you please see the Image bellow and express your thoughts about who was emitting the JWT in this case? That was an app generated by VS 2019, project AspNetCore 3.0 + Angular SPA + Authentication (individual user account) [The snippet with some comments](https://imgur.com/Xqrvkxs) I am not against what you say, just want to uncover the area and let the owner of the question to know more :)

Comment: It seems that is the only template using the IdentityServer as a built in one which serves for JWT generation. But yes, it is based on the IdentityServer... _Just an intention to bring more light in that thread_ :)